# Linux - Ubuntu: Get the global size of all pdf's inside a directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I have this filesystem on my server:

```
/a/b/c/<NAME>/*/deploy/*.pdf
```

My goal is to get the global size of all PDF files inside of /a/b/c/. So, I should get the size of all the pdf's for all  directories and inside the deploy directory.

I have tryed:

```
sudo du -ch $(sudo find . -type f \(  -name '*.pdf' \))
```

But without success. Any help is welcome.

Comment: `du -hsc /a/b/c/<NAME>/*/deploy/*.pdf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /a/b/c/*/deploy -name *.pdf | xargs du -ch
```

Comment: Looks nice, thank you very much. One question, if I would like to exclude some folders from <NAME>, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes `find` is a very powerful tool, you can exclude some sub-directories. Take time to read its documentation.